# htaccess redirect page and folder to use file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make the URL "/products" show the file "products-all.php". "products/xxx" and "products/xxx/xx" already work, but I can't get the first one to work. Any ideas?

It used to be just products.php but it interfered with the subcats.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/products$ products-all.php (I get file not found)
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/]+)/?$ products-cat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product-detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Make leading & trailing slash options as `RewriteRule ^/?products/?$ products-all.php` to `RewriteRule ^/products$ products-all.php [L,NC]`

Comment: If this is from .htaccess, remember paths there are relative to RewriteBase and shouldn't start with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code , first you catch all none files including directories by this conditions `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` so , unless the request contains file ,otherwise will go though this rule `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`.

you should add this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to exclude directories .

The second problem is this line `RewriteRule ^/products$ products-all.php` here you matched products only with `/products$` and it should match  products/ `products/$` so. it should be `RewriteRule ^products/$ products-all.php`  then your code should look like the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/$   products-all.php 
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/]+)/?$ products-cat.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product-detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, thanks for the answer, I tried your code but when I go to /products I still get a "File not found.", all the others work

I tried erase the ^/products/$ line and changing the file name to just products.php but now all products and products/... show the products.php file

Comment: did you clear your browser cache ? if not , clear it and test it again

Comment: is  products directory exist ? if it is exist updated code will work fine with products and products/